# some code to combine txt files with removing words in the beginning

Tags: python, pandas

Good day to everyone!

The thing is I have some txt files and I have script to put them together. Every txt file start from:

```
Export Type:                        by LAI\GCI\SAI
LAI\GCI\SAI:                        fjdfkj
HLR NUMBER:                         NA
Routing Category:                   NA
Telephone Service:                  NA
Export User Scope:                  Attached & Detached User
Task Name:                          lfl;sfd
Data Type:                          col1/col2
Begin Time of Exporting data:       2019-4-14 19:41
=================================
col1                    col2         
40188e5464645645         54634565754     
401884645645564         54545454564
401087465836453         54545454565     
401885645656567         53434343435
401084569498484         54342340788
401088465836453         56767686334
401439569345656         64545467558
401012993933334         55645342352
401034545566463         34353463464
```

I would like to combine just starting from col1 and col2(without names of colums), but script combine them with words in the beginning too. Could you update this script?

```
import fileinput
import glob

file_list = glob.glob("*.txt")

with open('resultfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    input_lines = fileinput.input(file_list)
    file.writelines(input_lines)
```

and another question is I would like to get rid of 5 in the beginning of values in col2 and also erase all rows that doesnt start from 40108/ 40188/401088e. columns are really long. I have in sum 50-60 txt files. Thank you!

In the end should look like this:

```
40188e464645645         4634565754     
401884645645564         4545454564
401087465836453         4545454565     
401885645656567         3434343435
401084569498484         4342340788
401088465836453         6767686334
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First loop by all files from list, then by lines and filter strings by `startswith` with tuple:

```
with open('resultfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    for f in file_list:
        with open(f, 'r') as f1:
            for line in f1:
                if line.startswith(('40108','40188','401088')):
                    file.writelines(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Pandas`'s `skiprows` to skip the first few rows:

```
data = pd.read_csv('file.txt', skiprows=10)
```

Results:

```
       col1                    col2         
0  40188e5464645645        54634565754     
1  401884645645564         54545454564
2  401087465836453         54545454565     
3  401885645656567         53434343435
4  401084569498484         54342340788
5  401088465836453         56767686334
6  401439569345656         64545467558
7  401012993933334         55645342352
8  401034545566463         34353463464
```

Comment: I can skip in 1 file, but I every txt files has this 10 rows, i d like to combine them all without first 10 rows